# CSS child margins don't extend parent

Tags: html, css

I got a css problem. Consider the following layout:

```
<div class="footer-container" style="background: #ff00ff">
 <footer class="wrapper"><h4 style="margin: 20px 0">Some Headline</h4></footer> </div>
```

The vertical margins of h4 don't extend the container div, Instead they "spill over", so that there is a 20px margin outside the container div above and below, which doesn't have any backgroundcolour.
I know that vertical margins of adjacent elements collapse but this seems to something else.

Thank your for your replies!

Comment: CSS has this thing called collapsing margins.  http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#collapsing-margins

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adding `overflow:auto` to your containing div would fix your collapsing margin issue:

```
<div class="footer-container" style="background: #ff00ff;overflow:auto">
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/DGBMR/)**

Comment: This probably seems odd to most people. Can you offer an explanation of why this works? Also, there is a list of other situations in which margins will not collapse [here](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/collapsingmargins).

Comment: okay, thanks. So, this is how it is sopposed to be according to the specs?

Answer (score 0):

Kind of hacky but if you don't want `overflow: auto` for some reason you can use `padding: .1px 0` on the parent, which will be rendered as 0 in all modern browsers.